# Strange Failed to load template with AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying something very basic where i have folder structure something like

[image]

This is my HTML file:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title> Using Angular JS</title>
      <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

  <ul>
   <div data-ng-view=""></div>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my app.js

```
'use strict';
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/view1', {
       templateUrl: "view1.html",
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/view2', {
       templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/view1'
      });
  }]);
```

and finally controller.js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
   $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S1',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi1',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™1111',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
  }]);
```

while running this sample i am getting 
[image]

i have tried different combinations of loading templates like:

templateUrl: "file:///E:/TryDemos/hemantTry/view1.html",
  templateUrl: "/hemantTry/view1.html",
  templateUrl: "/view1.html"

etc etc...

but couldn't able to rectify what is the actual problem

any help or hint will be appreciated

Just a heads up: while pasting these files in VS empty project is working fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `./view1.html`?

Comment: Did you open `index.html` directly to your browser?

Comment: Try running your app through your local web server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the application by opening a regular file (`index.html`) in the browser. Angular will try to load templates through [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest) requests which will fail since you there's no http server. There are couple of ways to solve it:

- use [**Grunt**](http://gruntjs.com/) with [**Yeoman**](http://yeoman.io/) to generate application template and add your files there and then enjoy the simplified development workflow with `grunt serve`
- use [**http-server**](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) to start an http server from your project directory

Answer (score 1):

To be very precise with the solution please check the notes below.

1. 'phonecatControllers' do not inject it in angular.module in your **app.js**
2. Remove controller from your route mechanism **just keep only templateUrl** that's enough controller is written there if you want to attest the controller to the template at runtime which is not necessary in your case.
3. In your controller remove the following lines.

   ```
   'use strict';    
   /* Controllers */    
   var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
   ```

and your controller name must be like

```
phonecatApp .controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope',
```

4. Its is preferred to use **ng-view instead of data-ng-view** as an attribute.
5. Then you can have your template path as /view1.html or ./view1.html all are fine you done need to give an absolute path.

Hope this resolves your query

Comment: If you still face an issue create a plunker if will make the relevant changes and will help you out :) .

Comment: After all this try running it in firefox as it allows XHR requests without any server. or if you want to run it in Chrome then make sure your web security is disabled in Chrome.

Comment: Hi Wasim. thanks for you reply .
I have tried what you are suggesting already. then i moved to angular official tutorial site. the code above is highly inspired from angular official tutorial. 

but still i will  incorporate changes suggest by you and let you know if it works fine.. thanks again :)

Comment: @AjayKotnala if this does not help kindly create a plunder an comment the path will surely get back to you on this.